# Beautifulsoup to retrieve the href list

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

Thanks for attention!
I'm trying to retrieve the href of products in search result.
For example this page:

However When I narrow down to the product image class, the retrived href are image links....
Can anyone solve that? Thanks in advance!

```
url = 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Husky/N-5yc1vZrd/Ntk-All/Ntt-chest%2Band%2Bcabinet?Ntx=mode+matchall&NCNI-5'
content = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
content = preprocess_yelp_page(content) 
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

content = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'content dynamic'})
draft = str(content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(draft)
items = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'cell_section1'})
draft = str(items)
soup = BeautifulSoup(draft)
content = soup.findAll('div',{'class':'product-image'})
draft = str(content)
soup = BeautifulSoup(draft)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to load the content of each found tag with `BeautifulSoup` over and over again.

Use [`CSS selectors`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors) to get all product links (`a` tag under a `div` with `class="product-image"`)

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'http://www.homedepot.com/b/Husky/N-5yc1vZrd/Ntk-All/Ntt-chest%2Band%2Bcabinet?Ntx=mode+matchall&NCNI-5'
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib2.urlopen(url))

for link in soup.select('div.product-image > a:nth-of-type(1)'):
    print link.get('href')
```

Prints:

```
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-41-in-16-Drawer-Tool-Chest-and-Cabinet-Set-HOTC4016B1QES/205080371
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-26-in-6-Drawer-Chest-and-Cabinet-Combo-Black-C-296BF16/203420937
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-52-in-18-Drawer-Tool-Chest-and-Cabinet-Set-Black-HOTC5218B1QES/204825971
http://www.homedepot.com/p/Husky-26-in-4-Drawer-All-Black-Tool-Cabinet-H4TR2R/204648170
...
```

`div.product-image > a:nth-of-type(1)` CSS selector would match every first `a` tag directly under the `div` with class `product-image`.

To save the links into a list, use a *list comprehension*:

```
links = [link.get('href') for link in soup.select('div.product-image > a:nth-of-type(1)')]
```

Comment: Awesome! Can you show me how to save them into the list? So I can actually output them.